# TypeError when trying to fetch JSON data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I'm trying to fetch JSON data from this link https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json using this code

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json/",
  success: function (data) {
    $("h5").each(function () {
      var code = $(this).data("code"); // atribut data-code
      $(this).html(data[code]["location"]);
    });
  },
});
```

It's working fine and the  tag is also set to the value I wanted to, but when I check the console I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
```

and it points to this line

```
$(this).html(data[code]["location"]);
```

how fix that?

Comment: Do you know what data is in the `data` variable? I'm pretty sure it's not whatever you think it is, which is why you're not getting the return you want. the request is returning fine sine the success function is running. You should console.log the data so you can inspect what's contained in that variable.

Comment: But the answer, is whatever is contained in the `code` variable doesn't exist in the `data` variable and then you try to pull `location` from an undefined value. You need to make sure whatever is stored in `code` is actually available in `data` and if it doesn't exist you need to return early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is contained in the `code` variable doesn't exist in the `data` object, which means it returns `undefined`. And then you're trying to call the `location` property on `undefined` which doesn't exist so it returns an error. You can prevent it with an early return:

```js
var code = $(this).data("code");
if (!data[code]) return;
$(this).html(data[code]["location"]);
```

Or if you need to add something to those elements no matter if it exists or not you could instead do something like:

```js
var code = $(this).data("code");
if (!data[code]) {
  $(this).html('Value does not exist');
  return;
};
$(this).html(data[code]["location"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have some `<h5>` elements that do not have a `code` [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property so you're essentially trying to use

```js
data[undefined].location
```

which will never work.

Make sure you're only looking at the elements with the appropriate data

```js
$.getJSON("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json")
  .done(data => {
    $("h5[data-code]").each((_, h5) => {
      $(h5).html(data[h5.dataset.code]?.location)
    })
  })
```